# Angularjs, Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a problem with code below. It should remove html tags from paste event for whole Angular application. This code works fine in Chrome and Safari, but when i try it in Mozilla, it doesn't work. When i try to remove e.preventDefault() it execute command execCommand() successfully, but if i let there e.preventDefault(), execCommand() doesn't work. Is there anybody who could help me with this problem? Thanks for answers.

```
$document.bind("paste", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var text = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");        
            $document[0].execCommand("insertHTML", true, text);
        });
```

Comment: Do you see any error in console.log

Comment: console is without errors, i can give console.log message after execCommand and it writes me what i want. I think that problem is something with preventDefault function which have maybe different behaivior in Firefox.

Comment: Give a try -  e.preventDefault(e);

Comment: The same behavior as with e.preventDefault()

Comment: Please share the link.